# Distinguishing decorated class methods in a typescript type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I want to create a generic type which picks only decorated methods from a class definition.

```
function test(ctor: any, methodName: any) {}

class A {
    @test
    public x() {}

    public y() {}
}

type DecoratedOnly<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends /* Magic Happens */ ? T[P] : never;
};

let a: DecoratedOnly<A> = {} as any;
a.x(); // ok
a.y(); // never!
```

Is it possible to infer decorated methods of a class, so `DecoratedOnly` generic type keeps decorated `x()` method as is and omits non-decorated `y()` method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see the answer is probably "no".  Decorators don't currently mutate types, so the type system won't notice a difference between decorated and undecorated methods.  People have asked for something like this for class decorators (as opposed to a method decorator like you're using), [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881)... but it's a controversial issue.  Some people feel very strongly that decorators should be unobservable by the type system, whereas others feel just as strongly otherwise. And until decorators in JavaScript become finalized, the maintainers of TypeScript are not likely to make any changes to the way they work, so I wouldn't expect any immediate resolution here.

---

But what if we back up and try to come up with a solution that has the same effect as applying those decorators while keeping track of what's happening in the file system?

To get something concrete to work with, I'm going to make `test()` do something:

```
function test(
  target: any,
  propertyKey: string,
  descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
) {
  console.log(
    "decorated test on target",
    target,
    "propertyKey",
    propertyKey,
    "descriptor",
    descriptor
  );
}
```

And when you make `A` like this:

```
class A {
  @test
  public x() {}

  public y() {}
}
```

You get the following log: `decorated test on target Object { … } propertyKey x descriptor Object { value: x(), writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true }`

---

Since we can't detect when decorators are applied, what if we didn't use the `@test` decoration style at all, but instead called the actual `test` function on the property descriptor, which is what method decorators are compiled to anyway?  If we make our own apply-instance-method-decorator function, we can make that function both do the decoration *and* keep track of which methods were decorated in the type system.  Something like this:

```
function decorateInstanceMethods<T, K extends Extract<keyof T, string>>(
  ctor: new (...args: any) => T,
  decorator: (
    target: any,
    propertyKey: string,
    descriptor: PropertyDescriptor
  ) => void,
  ...methodsToDecorate: K[]
): T & { decoratedMethods: K[] } {
  methodsToDecorate.forEach(m =>
    decorator(
      ctor.prototype,
      m,
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ctor.prototype, m)!
    )
  );
  return Object.assign(ctor.prototype, {
    decoratedMethods: methodsToDecorate
  });
}
```

That function could be hidden away in a library somewhere.  And here's how you'd make `A` and decorate it with `test`:

```
class A {
  public x() {}
  public y() {}
}

const DecoratedAPrototype = decorateInstanceMethods(A, test, "x");
```

That ends up logging the same thing as before: `decorated test on target Object { … } propertyKey x descriptor Object { value: x(), writable: true, enumerable: false, configurable: true }`

But now, `DecoratedAPrototype` is `A.prototype` with an added `decoratedMethods` property, whose type is `Array<"x">`, so you can do this:

```
type DecoratedOnly<
  T extends {
    decoratedMethods: (keyof T)[];
  }
> = Pick<T, T["decoratedMethods"][number]>;

const a: DecoratedOnly<typeof DecoratedAPrototype> = new A();
a.x(); // okay
a.y(); // error, property "y" does not exist on DecoratedOnly<typeof DecoratedAPrototype>
```

You can see that the `A` type still doesn't know anything about which methods were decorated, but `DecoratedAPrototype` does.  And that is enough to give you the behavior you're looking for (I used [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk) so the omitted properties are just not-known-to-exist and not explicitly `never`... it's not super important I guess)

Does that work for you?  Yes, it's a bit more complicated than just using decorators, but it's the closest I could get to what you want.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEBJYATCwAuSDeAsAFBJKiSwLIDCArgE71bYBqE9UAlgPbD7GlSAM1rB42Hn2zRsACgGDS2EPQDmEbAC4kIYAE8ANAsUx63GO2x6A0hD3ao2ep2CqjJRUkxR4zmNm56bQAFMwt6KwARaF9Of0DjJABKfg9FeF4obgAbCAA6bO5VeTTPACJMDPoQaXQkaUckXnqVdWwy909BZTUNTq6kMtNzSxs7DsSTMNHbQ0nBCpi-APoJ0sVvWPj6eaSAbkSAX2JE+GyQKCgkAEFUroABBux5mFoAI2zOeCQAD1kUvDHIgvd6fb56f74IGKaFIIEKcjQOCIJDBbiXTgfCAAZRytAkzUIpREYgJfEqgRqEDQjl0iAAshoABbcdBQAA8ABUDEhrEgID9pBgrgBRQXVcTsgDWdm4QiQ3KQjmcrgAfKqSl1xIFtMAIAB3JCyPIm1pQbS6PQpAC8qoV-Q2ECqNR1RvmSlaGgt+gdnmG4SsswcThcbndXiWcRWIWmET00R8ywS62SSFtSAAbtxOOhfaQTXlINgWWzOdxos7pNprABtAC6iSS2k5SAAZPgI5WIOhGcXWebefW4XdPEWS1AyxXKdI8kJAiKEEzZGA06rwxTqitNQNSNr6HlhgErBY86PT4oAPJvABWTuweTaF-1wFCIzjCa2W73B7MR70J6QMAkgAQnDJJdgOFMmGwBg+CvW9xDyC4uFUYBZG-Q9uGPCAeSJHcNypHtmX7bQx37ScnWnCB5kOfYjhOYlRHESR6hkbdFB6NpvTmFN-RmOxgxVMMU02JMglRWMokjbZGxHdJMhyfJCmKcNFi7OoniaKRPXac8Wl6bA9KGSSxj0NYdz4uNZiM0So0CcyBlsmSUzo0p4VKM5kJuOTBFeD4vl+SFARBfzwSC2FSHc+TgEaKdN27a5Xz-Cw007KiaWUMQIF7cdZGuHknh5MofjKVzEmwpA4sIi9gGyPR2XmFsBSFNkfMddScpIo0ZT0OUFSSetIK6CKkDta1US+KUuR5TkazUqiiL7NkyjrGtgFoMA3nYOtVUg05MlwEBtCq2oarq9lsL6k6EqSrD-wgMayANG5-iGwQQDyP59iQAB6H6milEA9ESD6IW+v7+UYQIeUsqxBjMrxuGgMgsP5H5OEaZprvQM7gY8IEgSAA)