# Question about typing decorators in TypeScript

Tags: typescript, typescript-decorator

Is it possible in TypeScript to implement a decorator `@important` and a utility type `PickImportantProps` in a way that type `B` becomes `{ b: string }` in the following example?
Many thanks in advance :)

```js
// decorator
function important(...): ... {
  ...
}

type PickImportantProps<T> = ...

class A {
  a = 'a'

  @important()
  b = 'b'
}

type B = PickImportantProps<A> // <= should result in { b: string }
```

Comment: It's not really possible, but you can check the answer to this question for a long-winded workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039676/distinguishing-decorated-class-methods-in-a-typescript-type

Comment: Thanks hlfrmn for your answer and your link to the similar question on Stack Overflow. The answer there and the linked Github [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) are very informative.
BTW: There's a bounty of 50 credits offered for helpful answers. If you are interested then please open an actual answer for this question, as I cannot pay the bounty for a comment only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment it isn't possible to get this information at compile-time.

The answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58039676/distinguishing-decorated-class-methods-in-a-typescript-type) shows a possible workaround that essentially gives up the decorator syntax (`@decoratorName`).